# Reference and best bounds of $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Could someone please provide information about the best possible known bounds of the sum $$A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}?$$ Unconditionally, $A(x)=O(e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}})$ is known to me. Does there exist any better bound conditionally or unconditionally?

I am expecting a result like $A(x)=O(\frac1{\sqrt x})$ if Riemann Hypothesis is assumed. Is this true? What I could get is up on truth of RH $A(x)=O(x^{-1/2+\epsilon})$, which is not very hard to prove.

Any reference regarding conditional (RH) bound of $A(x)$ will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant to write $A(x)=O(\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x}))$ unconditionally.  The Vinogradov zero-free region should improve that to $O(\exp(-(\log x)^{\frac 23-\epsilon}))$ (indeed something a little more precise).  Mark Lewko has supplied the best known result on RH

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Alexey has pointed out the problem can be reduced, via [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), to understanding the asymptotic of Mertens' sum 
$$M(x) := \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n).$$
Conditional on the Riemann hypothesis, the best bound to date on Mertens' sum, [due to Soundararajan](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2542220) in 2009, is
$$M(x) \ll x^{1/2} e^{(\log(x))^{1/2} (\log\log(x))^{14}}.$$
In particular, this implies
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \ll \frac{e^{(\log(x))^{1/2} (\log\log(x))^{14}}}{x^{1/2}}.$$

Comment: Using Soundararajan's method, the power of $\log\log x$ in this estimate has been improved by Balazard & Roton: http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3587

Answer (score 1):

See [Mertens conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture). Summation by parts gives your sum from Mertens conjecture.

Comment: This is technically true, but Mertens conjecture has been disproved...