Behavior of $m(x)\sqrt{x}$ where $m(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$
Let $M(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)$ and $m(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.
We know that (it is not the best known bounds):
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} M(x)x^{-1/2} > 1$$
$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} M(x)x^{-1/2} < -1$$
Are there any references showing that (if true) we also have for some $c>0$:
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} m(x)x^{1/2} > c$$
$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} m(x)x^{1/2} < -c$$

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153695 for upper bounds on $|m(x)|$, but that doesn't address lower bounds. (I mistakenly thought this was a duplicate of that one, but it isn't.)

For the Mertens function $M(x)$, Kotnik & te Riele established:
$\limsup M(x)x^{-1/2} > 1.218$,
$\liminf M(x)x^{-1/2} < -1.229$.
However, analogous tight bounds for $m(x)x^{1/2}$ are unknown to me.

@Babar The inequalities by Kotnik & te Riele are not tight. It is expected that $\limsup M(x)x^{-1/2}=\infty$ and $\liminf M(x)x^{1/2}=-\infty$. By following my answer you should be able to find a numeric positive lower bound for $\limsup m(x)x^{1/2}$ and a numeric negative upper bound for $\liminf m(x)x^{1/2}$.

@GH from MO Thanks, I expressed myself poorly. I meant to say "the best known result" instead of "tight".

This is true by Exercise 4(b) for Section 15.1.1 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I (CUP, 2006). The inequality contained therein can surely be proved in much the same way as (15.13) in the book, with the help of Lemma 15.1.
